# is Semantic-ui depends on jquery or not?

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

I'm new to semantic-ui,

1) is **Semantic-ui depends on jquery  or not**?

2) if it depends **what are the components of semantic depends on jquery**?

3) if i **want to use jquery plugins is jquery library needed or Not if needed where can i place jquery library** in my html?(**means below the semantic js or above the semantic js**)

Comment: 1. Just Google `Semantic-ui depends on jquery` or have a peek in its source code to find any `jQuery` or `$`. 2. Have a peek. 3. Yes, since a webpage is loaded from top to bottom, you have to put independent js on top, then dependent js, so jQuery top, jQuery dependent below.

Comment: Then it's better to add Jquery before Semantic js file right?

Comment: Yes, jQuery first, followed by Semantic below that.